# How to create an XPath for this, suitable for Selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath

Please help me to create the Xpath for the following. I am using Selenium webdriver and have only IE browser. Following is the HTML:

```
<A
    title=""
    href="javascript:Plg({u:'/epace/starintfc.html?module=RUN_EVENT',p:0,nw:'0'});"
    p="eagle/pace/pace"
    la=""
    ml="%09NULL%09PLUGIN%09%2fepace%2fstarintfc.html%3fmodule%3dRUN_EVENT%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09%09"
    t="Plugin" gh="" g="Data Steward"
    pc="Eagle/PACE/PACE Components"
    ivname=""
><IMG id=Item.Img
      class=link
      src="/tpe/modules/site/img/menu_plugin.gif">Run An Event</A>
```

Comment: What element do you specifically wish to select - the link or the image? Can we see what you have attempted first? (I've reformatted your HTML to make it more readable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I prefer CSS over xPath because of it's simplicity, I will provide both the CSS and xPath solution:

Remember that you want to get the attribute of the elements that have the most specificity.  The answers below are the best of my ability, to determine which have the most specificity. ([see here](http://ddavison.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html) if you want to learn more about CSS and specificity of elements)

> If you are trying to select the first `<a>` element...

#### CSS:

```
a[href*='RUN_EVENT']
```

#### xPath:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'RUN_EVENT')]
```

> If you are trying to select the `<img>` that is inside of the `<a>` tag...

#### CSS:

```
a[href*='RUN_EVENT'] > img
```

#### xPath:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'RUN_EVENT')]/img
```

My guess is that you want the first one since it's a link, and I assume you want to invoke a click on it.

Comment: You are right I am trying to invoke the link on click.

Comment: cool. let me know if this helps! and if it answers your question, go ahead and upvote and accept

Comment: I tried both the suggestions XPATH & CSS & had following results: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //a[contains(@href,'RUN_EVENT')] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout                                                                    
Code Used:
String str = "//a[href*='RUN_EVENT']";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(str)).click();

Comment: look at the source, is that stuff in an `<iframe>`?

Comment: Yes it is Frame as I can see <Frameset & <Frame tags but the HTML I shared is inside Table tag

Comment: so what you need to do then, is switch to that frame using [`driver.switchTo().frame`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html), *then* do my solution above

Comment: Thanks ,worked after switch : //a[contains(@href, 'RUN_EVENT')]